# How to Integrate siri with flutter app and also do a background api call

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, siri, flutter-method-channel

I want to create a flutter app which will support siri and from device's home screen, when I ask a question to siri it should recognize by the app (should not open the app) do a api request in background and get the response give it back to siri.

Is there any package that I can make use of or have to use method channel?

Comment: Did you got any solution, I am in need of the same?